# How to allow form control to accept quotation marks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting value from form a control as below:

```
string name= formCollection["name"].ToString();
```

Is there a way to include the quotation marks inside of the string itself - so that the final string will be `"name"` instead of `name`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since `"` is a special character, you have to escape it using the escape sequence `\"`:

```
var someString = "\"name\"";
```

This will produce a string variable `someString` with the value `"name"`